# How to loop through arrays starting at different index while still looping through entire array in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to start loop through array at index (say “5” or any other) instead of beginning of the array in swift

```
for (index, value) in array.enumerate() {
  // do something 
}
```

Comment: Related: [How to loop through an array from the second element in elegant way using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070937/how-to-loop-through-an-array-from-the-second-element-in-elegant-way-using-swift)

Answer (score 3):

Use `dropFirst` to ignore the first items:

```
for (index, value) in array.enumerated().dropFirst(5) {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `where` clause

```
for (index, value) in array.enumerate() where index > 4 { ...
```

By the way: Update your Swift version. Swift 2 is dead